# Feed Me Import Categories from CSV

Tags: plugin-feedme, import

I am trying to import some categories from a CSV into Craft entries (a categories field). Everything else imports ok apart from the categories

I have created the categories in admin with the same name as the CSV categories but when I import nothing gets selected.

I have the categories formatted in one column in the CSV seperated with a comma .e.g "Branding,Marketing,Design," (I read somewhere this is how it can be done).

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks 
Malcolm

Comment: Does it work if you just import one category? As far as I remember, you'll have to use a different delimiter if you're importing multiple relations per cell, see "dataDelimiter" here: https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/get-started/configuration.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docs...if you add `config/feed-me.php` to your project containing

```
<?php

return [
    '*' => [
        'dataDelimiter' => '-|-',
    ]
];
```

and format your CSV like

```
id,title,categories,city
17746,Imported title,Category 1-|-Category 2-|-Category 3,Bradford
```

should get you where you want to be.